# Need help in solving this indefinite integral.

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I tried solving 
$$\int{\sqrt{\frac{\cos(x) - \cos^3 (x)}{1 - \cos^3(x)}}}\, dx$$
And was able to reduce it to
$$\int{\sqrt{\frac{\cos (x) + \cos^2(x)}{1 + \cos(x) + \cos^2(x)}}}\, dx$$
I guess i got myself landed on another planet!
Thankful if anyone helps.

Comment: How did you even arrive at your reduction? **Spoiler:** It is wrong, since if you put $x=0\text{rad}$ in both expressions, their values don't match up.

Comment: Extremely sorry, I actually mistyped the question.

Comment: I think it is $\cos x -\cos ^3 x$ in the numerator, based on your reduction.

Comment: Sorry, yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Put $\cos x=t$

You'll obtain, after simplification,
$$\int{\sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t^3}}}dt$$

Now, put $t^{3/2}=a$ and proceed to obtain an expression in $\sin^{-1}$.